# Trigger Emails/Handlers on Webform submissions update

Tags: 8, hooks, webforms, emails

Is there a way to trigger the `Emails/Handlers`, When webform submission has been updated. I'm using `webform_mailchimp` as a handler. When I'm submitting a new record, handler is working fine and  I can receive the data into my Mailchimp account. I have a function to update the submission via code. But it doesn't trigger, when I update the same record.  Following is my code to update the webform submission:

```
$webform = Webform::load('my_form');
$is_open = WebformSubmissionForm::isOpen($webform);
$sid = 2;

if ($is_open === TRUE) {
    // Load submission
    $webform_submission = WebformSubmission::load($sid);

    // Modify submission values
    $webform_submission->setElementData('preferred_date', $form_state->getValue('preferredDate'));
    $webform_submission->setElementData('preferred_time', $form_state->getValue('preferredTime'));

    // Validate submission.
    $errors = WebformSubmissionForm::validateWebformSubmission($webform_submission);

    // Check there are no validation errors.
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Failed! Please contact the administrator.'), 'error');
    }
    else {
        // Submit values and get submission ID.
        $webform_submission = WebformSubmissionForm::submitWebformSubmission($webform_submission);
        drupal_set_message(t("Success! ".$webform_submission->id()), 'status');
    }
}
```

1. Is there a way to trigger the handler through code(programmatically)?
2. Is there a default configuration in the CMS?

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is untested but should point you in the right direction.

```
// Get a handler.
$webform_submission = WebformSubmission::load(WEBFORM_ID)
$handlers = $webform_submission->getWebform()->getHandlers();
$handler = $handlers[HANDLER_ID];

// Invoke submit form.
@see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::submitForm
$form = []; // Might need to get the $form.
$form_state = new FormState(); // Might need to be build the form state.
$handler->submitForm($form, $form_state, $webform_submission);
```

@see \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::invokeHandlers

@see \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::invokeWebformHandlers

Comment: How do I get $form and $form_state from $webform or $webform_submission objects? Or do I need to build them in another way? My code is in a class which extends the `ControllerBase` class...

Answer (score 2):

```
  $webform_submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load(submission_id);
  /** @var \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform $webform */
  $webform = $webform_submission->getWebform();
  /** @var \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandler\EmailWebformHandler $handler */
  $handler = $webform->getHandler(handler_id);
  $message = $handler->getMessage($webform_submission);
  $handler->sendMessage($webform_submission, $message);
```

In case the above solution doesn't alternative can be this as well.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the Mailchimp handler supports it, you can select the option to fire the handler "...when submission is updated" within the handler settings.

[image]

Comment: You can also uncheck all of them, and it will only send when using the "Resend" button or from code.